# Baking in username and pw in .xspf file

Tags: passwords, vlc-media-player

I have configured a VLC .xpsf file to point to a video stream, which prompts for a username and pw.  Is it possible to somehow bake the username and pw into the file so that it is automatically sent?

.xpsf file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
    <trackList>
        <track><location>rtsp://192.168.8.108:554/live/ch00_0</location><title>Full resolution</title></track>
        <track><location>rtsp://192.168.8.108:554/live/ch01_0</location><title>Half resolution</title></track>
    </trackList>
</playlist>
```

Comment: You should give a try to this syntax: rtsp://user:pass@192.168.8.108:554/.....

Comment: This seemed to work.  Promote this to an answer and you will receive credit.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VLC [MRL](https://wiki.videolan.org/Media_resource_locator/)s are based on [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)s which [syntax](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) allows for the insertion of optional scheme-specific *userinfo*:

```
# (simplified)
scheme://[userinfo@]host[:port]/path
```

with the `userinfo` field taking almost always the form `user[:password]`.
Hence, you can inject your username and password this way:

```
rtsp://user:password@host:port/path
```

which gives you this `xpsf` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist version="1" xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/">
  <trackList>
    <track>
      <location>rtsp://user:password@192.168.8.108:554/live/ch00_0</location>
      <title>Full resolution</title>
    </track>
    <track>
      <location>rtsp://user:password@192.168.8.108:554/live/ch01_0</location>
      <title>Half resolution</title>
    </track>
  </trackList>
</playlist>
```